# Visual Studio: Change the build path in user file only

Tags: visual-studio

I can change the build path for a project in Visual Studio from the Project Properties dialog. But making a change to the .csproj file would interfere with the setup of other developers on the team, since this file is checked into source control.

So how can I change the build path so that this change only goes into the .user file?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

1. In Visual Studio, make a change in the project properties.
2. Identify what changed in the .csproj file (using a diff tool)
3. Put that change into the .csproj.user file, making sure to include the xml structure.
4. Revert the change in the .csproj file so it remains unchanged.

Example of a changed path in a .csproj.user file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>..\..\..\CustomPath\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```